# Determine if an item or nothing was clicked in a ListView

Tags: listview, vb6

I am having a problem with a ListView selection on VB6 Classic.

I have a listview with a few items but when i select somewhere out of the text lines it goes automatically to the default/first item.

[image: listview]

What i am looking for is to find a way to "select nothing" when the user clicks on any other place than the list text of the listview.

This is the listview code:

```
Private Sub lsvArticle_Click()
   Dim mArticleNumber As Integer, mArticleIndex As Integer
   Dim Splitted() As String

   Splitted = Split(lsvArticle.SelectedItem.Text, ":")
   mArticleNumber = CInt(Trim(Splitted(0)))
   mArticleIndex = ArticleNb2ListIdx(mArticleNumber - 1)
   mNewValue = mArticleIndex
   txtValueNew.Text = A_ArticlesDef(mNewValue).W_Art_Numb & " : " & A_ArticlesDef(mNewValue).W_Art_Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as an image

Comment: Edit it into the question, not as a comment

Comment: Ok, done. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ideas come to mind.  You will need to decide which is best for your situation.  The first idea is to respond to the `ItemClick` event.  This event is only fired if you click on an item.

```
Private Sub lsvArticle_ItemClick(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
   txtValueNew.Text = Item.Text
End Sub
```

The second idea is to respond to the `MouseUp` event in conjunction with performing a `HitTest`.  If `HitTest` is Nothing then you clicked in a blank area.

```
Private Sub lsvArticle_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
   If Not lsvArticle.HitTest(x, y) Is Nothing Then
      txtValueNew.Text = lsvArticle.SelectedItem.Text
   End If
End Sub
```